# Show that they are not the boundaries of any disjointly embedded disks.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is an exercise in Hatcher's topology [book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf). It's in Page 176, problem 4(b).

> In the unit sphere $S^{p+q-1}$,let $S^{p-1}$ and $S^{q-1}$ be the subspheres consisting of points whose last $q$ and first $p$ coordinates are zero respectively.
>
> $(b)$ Show that $S^{p-1}$ and $S^{q-1}$ are not the boundaries of any pair of disjointly embedded disks $D^p$ and $D^p$ in $D^{p+q}$.

I suppose the pair exists. Then $D^{p+q}-D^p$ and $D^{p+q}-D^p$ cover $D^{p+q}$. If $p,q>1$, I can use Mayer Vietoris sequence to get $\tilde{H_i}(D^{p+q}-D^p-D^p)=\mathbb{Z}$ when $i=p-1, q-1$. (From problem 3, we know that $\tilde{H_i}(D^{p+q}-D^p)=\mathbb{Z}$ when $i=q-1$.) Then I don't know what to do next to get the contradiction.

Comment: Hint: You need to use the linking number and the fact that it is independent of the choice of disks bounding spheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me update what I have so far.

Proof: Suppose $D^{p}\cap D^q= \varnothing$, then we have following commutative diagram.
$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_{i}(S^{p+q-1} - S^{q}) @. H_i(D^{p},S^{p-1}) @>\cong>> \tilde{H}_{i-1} (S^{p-1})\\
@V g_1 V \cong V @VV \text{inclusion} V @V g_3 V\cong V \\
H_{i}(D^{p+q}-D^{q})@>0>>H_i(D^{p+q}-D^{q}, S^{p+q-1}-S^{q}) @>f>> H_{i-1}(S^{p+q-1} - S^{q})\\
@.@.@V g_2 V \cong V\\
@.@.H_{i-1}(D^{p+q}-D^{q})
\end{CD}
$

$g_1$, $g_2$ isomorphism by problem 3. $g_3$ isomorphism by problem 4(a). So $f$ is zero map. So this commutative diagram factors through $0$.

Contradiction. So $D^{p}\cap D^q \neq \varnothing$